# Notificação chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notificação

Alguém sabe ou já usou isso [chrome notificação](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) e sabe como funciona?

porque quando tento usar `webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification()` ele da erro `ReferenceError: webKitNotifications is not defined` alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: +1 pela questão sobre a API de notificações... apesar do erro estar ocorrendo por causa de um simples typo! Essa API é muito f@)@!

Comment: @MiguelAngelo é que pena que ela não funciona em todos os browsers

Comment: Além de não funcionar em todos, chrome e firefox diferem na implementação, ainda por cima. Mas há esperança! =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está escrevendo errado:

```
window.webkitNotifications // correto: letra 'k' minúscula

window.webKitNotifications // errado (letra 'k' maiúscula está errada)
```

O nome oficial da API é `Notifications`, e no firefox já pode ser usada com esse nome, assim:

```
window.Notifications
```

**Exemplo de uso:**

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DCcH/)

**Referência:**

Html5Rocks: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/?redirect_from_locale=pt

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: é isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda..

Comment: Aqui tem um [exemplo prático](https://jsbin.com/ziwod/2/edit?html,js,output) de notificação.